# Does France consider an HVDC grid connection to French Guyana?

Tags: france, energy-independence

An aspect that seems to plague the idea of a [European supergrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_super_grid) for electricity (i.e. the concept of a renewables-dominated electricity grid with continental or even intercontinental interconnectedness through High Voltage Direct Current (HVDC) cables to address the intermittency of the local renewable power generation) is the fact that in the evening time, there is not much land to the west of Spain/Portugal/UK to extract solar energy from. So trouble might arise on such evenings if e.g. simultaneously the wind stalls above the North Sea.

However, it seems possible to go next level with those HVDC cables and [bridge entire oceans with them](https://www.pv-magazine.com/2021/11/15/chile-wants-to-export-solar-energy-to-asia-via-15000km-submarine-cable/). When I started thinking what kind of options this could imply for Europe I was quickly reminded that France has a piece of land in Guyana, apparently with acceptable [irradiation characteristics](https://solargis.com/maps-and-gis-data/download/south-america). Does France have any plans for such a connection? Is there any public debate on this inside of France?

Comment: Has anyone actually built transoceanic HVDC cables? Longest one seems to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Sea_Link which is still rather short of crossing an ocean. The cost of that was €2 billion. Guyana-France distance is >10x that, so  €20 billion at least. Whether that pays off, and in what time frame etc.

Comment: There are many between the UK and the European continent.

Comment: The cost of HVDC scales slower than linear in the amount of power that the cable is supposed to transport. I think if you'd transport 10GW or more with it, its share in the project cost would be small. (I'll come back with some papers on the matter to back that up if you want)

Comment: Welcome aboard.  Climate change questions with a political angle *are* welcome here.  But I am deeply uncertain this is feasible in engineering and financial terms.  Also, while Guyana gets a lot of sun it is also covered by jungle and clear cutting to make space would not be welcomed by many.  In short, I don't think this has reached the feasibility stage where it would become a political issue, making this a question that seems off topic here.  Engineering, economic or climate change-only Qs have different Stack Exchange sites were they can be discussed.

Comment: Italian Philosophers 4 Monica: are you an expert on HVDC interconnectors? Are you French yourself or are you an expert on the French political debate? Read carefully the question that I have asked.

Comment: The question of whether it has been discussed by politicians is a factual political question that could be answered here. It may not seem the most interesting question about HVDC technology, but that's a matter of opinion. (Likewise the possibility of building a bridge between Scotland and Northern Ireland has been discussed by politicians despite being ridiculed by many engineers.)

Comment: Your question is not that complicated.  And, yes, I am French, at least originally.  And, yes, I spend plenty of time ruminating about climate change and renewables:  this seems like a pipe dream at this point in time.  The closest equivalents are cross-Med electrical feeds bringing in Sahara solar electricity and those are also not very much advanced and not on very much on the political radar, yet.

Comment: It may seem like a pipe dream to you, but the Xlinks project will start construction as soon as 2024, supply 10.5 GW generated in Morocco to the UK via a 3800 km HVDC line (that is incidentally +/- the distance from France to French Guyana, as the seagull flies). The price they are aiming for is a nice £48/MWh. I think there is reason to believe that this plan/announcement is not Musk-tier vaporware.

Comment: Response to first comment of thread (by Fizz): you cannot multiply by 10 since that price tag is dominated by the converter stations at either end of the cable. That price stays the same for a longer cable. Based on the wikipedia page, I arrive at a cost of €4.5 billion for 2000 MW over a distance of 4000km: that is quite cheap (for reference, a 1000 MW nuclear power plant in the good days would cost around 6 billion).

Comment: Found an open-access paper that discusses the challenges https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s41825-020-00032-z Didn't have time to read just yet. Skimming it, it seems depth is the biggest challenge. Heavy cables tend to be compromised when laid deep.

Comment: Why would they connect to French Guyana rather than, say, the USA?

Comment: @user253751 Oh, that's the first political, rather than engineering, aspect to this Q and that's easy enough:  it's all in the name.  French Guyana belongs to the French, at least for now.  Also, the US is not really, currently, in a position to export *excess* electricity on a steady basis.  Esp. not *green* excess electricity.

Comment: @user253751: Californian solar potential is of course even more powerful than the Guyanese (so is the Chilean potential) and its longitude also better to supply Western Europe with evening and night-time electricity. But in my experience people are anxious about such long-range international energy dependencies and they prefer policies that avoid them (which is of course difficult to reconcile with the philosophy behind supergrids).

Comment: No time to write an answer but it seems unlikely: 1. Macron's strategy against climate change is based mainly on nuclear energy. 2. Macron's government is not the most well-informed about the climate crisis and it is hard to imagine them taking innovative and bold measures in this domain: the Minister of Ecology decided to spend the summer explaining to people that they should turn off wifi when they go on vacations and should avoid sending unnecessary attached documents with emails...

Comment: @Taladris Thx for that information. But some oppoisition politicians must be opposed to Macron's nuclear plans, no? Do they sometimes sketch alternative plans? (I know of course that opposition politicians rarely do that: it is smarter for them to just attack the government's policy and keep their alternative policies a secret)